# select query inside for each loop of PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day! I am trying to get the user ids based on the names submitted on the input field. But the loop only returns the user id of the first selected user. Can somebody please help me?

Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['proponent'])){
    $proponent = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['proponent']);
    $myArray = explode(',', $proponent);

    $posts = array();

    foreach($myArray as $item) {
        $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) = '$item'";
        $get = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        array_push($posts, mysqli_fetch_assoc($get));
        print_r($posts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Don't run queries inside loops. You can easily hammer your DB. Instead, select multiple rows per item and iterate through the result-set afterwards. Depending on the size of items, you can even "batch" select.

Answer (score 2):

Using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only once will only get you the first row if it exists. So you will need to add this in a loop, say while loop like below in order for the mysqli_function to move it's pointer over the entire result set.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){
    $posts[] = $row;
 }
```

Comment: Hi. I tried adding this while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){
          $posts[] = $row["user_id"];
        } but it still just give the first ID. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @GailyGuzon If you directly run the query in Phpmyadmin, how many rows do you get?

Comment: Since the $item is from an array I can't check the rows of the query returns. But the query is working if I specify the string in '$item'. I am also suspecting that the problem is in the query, not the loop. But I don't know how to fix it. :(

Comment: @GailyGuzon First `var_dump($item)` to see what you get. Then, you can run the same query in Phpmyadmin and check

Comment: it returns a string, like: string(11) "gail manuel". i also tried echoing the $item in foreach and it returns all the strings in the array, it means it's working. It's just i don't get why the query only returns 1 row :(

Comment: @GailyGuzon I am assuming it is making a case sensitive match.

Comment: @GailyGuzon Looking at your code, `where IN` looks like a better option.

Comment: @GailyGuzon Also check for trailing and leading spaces. Use trim() for PHP. Also make sure your DB data doesn't have extra spaces either at the beginning or the end